# Need Solution With Identical Results To Flash - HTML 5 Compliant

Tags: javascript, html, flash, adobe-edge

I used to build sites that used flash for background animations & background movies while having regular (selectable) Html text on top.

Flash really fit the bill because it allowed for streaming movies WITHIN the animation itself, so you could layer things really well and get a very creative website going.

BUT FLASH IS DYING...

So I'm here to ask you good folks what solution (or solutions) should I look towards that can accomplish the same goals in modern non-Flash platforms (web-mobile etc).

It would need to:

- **Create animations that can have within them movie files. I would need to control the movies from the animation, not just slap them as background**

NOTE: I have looked at all kinds of plugins etc for putting a movie as a site background, but this would NOT yield the result I need as it is just a movie playing and cannot be scripted as an animation in Flash was. I also checked out Adobe Edge. It comes closest to what I need but I have found no way of working with video inside it the same as in Flash - Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm no Javascript maestro by any means. I would dive deeper into it but I'm not sure it would work for what I need.

I hope I have not confused you with this long winded question and I thank you for your help.

Comment: You could use a combination of full-background videos and CSS3 for animations, or even SVG. I guess it depends on the complexity of the animation. If it's very complex then flash might still be an option.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. The problem with that solution is that there is no way to connect the video with the animation. For example, how would I be able to put the video in a small box INSIDE the animation and script it to do something after it finishes playing etc? Basically there's no way to control it - I guess that would be my point.

Comment: Well, you can use Canvas if you need more complexity.

Comment: I have thought about that. Any suggestions how I would do that without diving into javascript hell :) ... Edge would work out so well if ONLY they had a way to work with video. Or maybe I'm missing something. Sorry but I've been out of the website building game for a few years :(

Comment: Mmm, I think you basically have to go through "hell" this time if you want to use the latest and greatest. Learning curve of canvas is not too bad.

Comment: Just to be clear - you're saying that the "canvas" tag would allow all that I need? If that's the case, then I guess it's a worthy time investment. I do however have to wonder why no app maker jumped on offering some shell for it - of course, with the option to dive into the nuts and bolts if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the html canvas element. You can pipe video to the canvas using a hidden video element and any animation you can think of is possible through canvas. Since these are dom elements, you can of course put other HTML on top of them.

For good canvas frameworks check: http://www.backslash.gr/content/blog/webdevelopment/7-10-javascript-canvas-frameworks

I'm personally a big fan of paper.js and processing.js

Comment: Thank you. As with elclanrs above, I'm beginning to see that the "canvas" tag is the way to go. In this case are there any apps out there than can provide some interface or is everything down to nuts & bolts coding. I've been out of the game for a few years so while I'm down for putting the effort to learn, I also need to look for any shortening of the learning curve if possible.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I don't know of any apps for creating canvas animations (such as things packaged with the adobe suite) so it might be down the regular coding. However, the frameworks above should make that easier.